# Specific class with anchor css

Tags: css, class, anchor

I am trying to override the style on the following HTML:

```
<a class="ui-state-default" href="#">7</a>
```

The issue is that the `ui-state-default` class is used in many other places so I cannot just update it. I have tried the following to no effect.

```
.ui-state-default a { 
    width:27px !important;
}

.ui-state-default: a {
    width:27px !important;
}

a.ui-state-default { 
    width:27px !important;
}
```

How can I target just this one anchor tag for a style change?

Comment: Post a small sample of the markup (HTML). Also, what is "html 7"?

Comment: We can't help you with what you provide, please show us your code

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not a good idea to put `inline css` but if You don't have any onther way than you could try **inline css** like this:  `<div class="ui-state-default" style="width:24px !important;">your stuff</div>`

The main part is `style="width:27px !important;"` to put in the html markup.

May be this also works `.ui-state-default a * { width:27px !important;}`